# One sql query to check for unique

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Mvc application, in registration form i have an area for email and name

Before registering i check that all fields are unique in the DB with the following code in service layer (I'm using `spring data`)

```
@Override
    public Optional<String> isUnuque(final Users user) {
        if (this.repository.findByEmail(user.getEmail()) != null) {
            return Optional.of("Your email is not unique");
        } else if (this.repository.findByName(user.getName()) != null) {
            return Optional.of("Your name is not unique");
        }
        return Optional.empty();

    }
```

Then in controller i check if Optional is present. But with this code i make 2 requests to the DB, i can use native query like this to make only one request:

```
select * from users where name = 'dd' or email = 'ddd@mail.ru'
```

But how would i know which parameter is not unique name or email?

Thank in advance

BTW i solved this problem with the following code

```
@Override
    public Optional<String> isUnuque(final Users user) {
        final Users dbUser = this.repository.findByEmailOrName(user.getEmail(), user.getName());
        if (dbUser != null) {
            if (user.getEmail().equals(dbUser.getEmail())) {
                return Optional.of("Not unique email");
            } else {
                return Optional.of("Not unique name");
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

But if there are any sql query that can do exactly what i want without double checking in service layer please write it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a java expert but as a database guy, I would say a better way would be to enforce the `UNIQUE` constraint on `name` and `email` in the table and handle the exception, which maintains the data integrity regardless of the application.

Another option is to get the count of emails and names with the given arguments.

```
SELECT count(CASE 
            WHEN name = :p_name
                THEN 1
            END) AS name_count
    ,count(CASE 
            WHEN email = :p_email
                THEN 1
            END) AS email_count
FROM users;
```

The `COUNT` function does not count nulls, so when condition in `CASE` is false( by default `NULL`), it adds 0 to the count. So, effectively the query would return `name_count` and `email_count` as 0 or 1 depending on the existing value, which you should be able to use in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Union All can do this.

```
select 'name' from users where name = 'dd'
union all
select 'email' from users where name = 'ddd'@mail.ru
```